# When is an observable chain triggered by main thread

Tags: java, java-8, rx-java, observable, rx-java2

I am getting information of a person from different service calls. Some that can be executed in parallel. Others are dependent on info returned by the parallel calls.
Once all the info is computed, I save the person info to a repository

Here is how I have setup my flow :

Parallel calls :

```
private Observable<Person> getDataForEval(Person person){
 Person person = new Person();
 Observable<Salary> observeSalary = getSalary(person).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io);
 Observable<HomeAddress> observeHome = getHomeAddress(person).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io);
 return  Observable.zip(observeSalary , observeHome , (salary, home) -> buildPersonAfterGettingData(salary,home));
}
```

Dependent Calculation :

```
private Observable<Person> getDataAfterCalc(Person person) {
  Observable<LoanEligiblity> loanEligible= getLoanEligibility(person);
  Observable<Tax> observeTax= getTax(person);
  return Observable.zip(loanEligible, observeTax, (loan, tax) ->
                buildFinalPersonInfo(loan, tax));
}
```

Chaining Both, in main thread :

```
Observable<Person> finalPersonInfo = getDataForEval.flatMap(person -> getDataAfterCalc(person));
finalPersonInfo.subscribe( finalPerson -> save(finalPerson));
```

Question - When is this flow triggered? My understanding is that when the main thread calls the subscribe method, the Observable.zip() - used to make the parallel calls - is triggered and the subsequent subscribers get the responses.

Is it correct? If I need to know time taken to process one person, can i calculate it as follows :

```
finalPersonInfo.onSubscribe(()->start).onTerminate(()->finish);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understand is almost right.

`zip` operator subscribe to its sources when downstream subscribe on it. See `ObservableZip#72` and `ObservableZip#110`.

But `zip` operator is nothing with parallel, parallel call is because `subscribeOn` operator.

You approach of measure time used to process one person is right.

By the way, you should use `Single` rather than `Observable` in this scene.

> The `Single` class implements the Reactive Pattern for a single value response. `Single` behaves the same as Observable except that it can only emit either a single successful value, or an error (there is no "onComplete" notification as there is for Observable)

<sub>*My RxJava source version is 2.1.13*</sub>